# How to re-sign an existing android app after modifing it

Tags: android

every one .
now I am in a project upon android system application source code with the Android v 2.1r1 : Contacts .
I have modify the source code and run it on the emulator successfully..

but i get a problem on publishing it to my android phone with the same system version because of without signing it. 
  how can i do if i want to publish it to my android phone after modifying it?
  do i need to resign the Contacts.apk built by mm ?
  can i just signing the Contacts.apk built by mm?
  thx for your reading and replies !

Comment: I have got some information here ..thx every on .. (:
http://source.android.com/porting/release_keys.html

Comment: thx for all replies ,I think i have gone the wrong way of build the APK file using mm support by android sdk .

Comment: as the mm will automatic sign the apk files with a debug signing .so i can't sign apk file created by use the mm command ..and I   find I can't build the android system project immediately with ant because the hide api of googles ..at the end ..I solve this problem with two steps :

Comment: first I build the modified source code(android source code imported as a java project)  and then i use the ant to build it with the template ant tasks provide by android sdk (android ant build template task file is in <SDK>/platforms/<target_platform>/templates/android_rules.xml .and then i commented the task compile content :javac  and  just copied the classes build by eclipse to the destination fold the bin folder...

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and accept it to help others who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You do exactly what the title of your post says.  Re-sign the app with your own key.  Google isn't about to give you theirs.  So you need to create your own key and sign your app with it.

If you don't know how to do this, there are a ton of resources/tutorials/walk throughs already on-line.

I suggest starting [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html)

Answer (score 0):

As user432209 said, you will have to resign the package with your own key. It sounds like you might also be having an issue with your version of Contacts conflicting with the version on your phone. If so, you may need to change the package name.